# addrole use discord.py bot

Tags: discord, discord.py

The bot should give someone a roll when writing a command called Test_Role Google says it's done but I'm full of errors I tried to find a complete solution but everything failed

Ignoring exception in command addrole:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\edgar\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "C:\Users\edgar\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 851, in invoke
await self.prepare(ctx)
File "C:\Users\edgar\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 778, in prepare
if not await self.can_run(ctx):
File "C:\Users\edgar\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1076, in can_run
return await discord.utils.async_all(predicate(ctx) for predicate in predicates)
File "C:\Users\edgar\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 338, in async_all
for elem in gen:
File "C:\Users\edgar\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1076, in 
return await discord.utils.async_all(predicate(ctx) for predicate in predicates)
File "C:\Users\edgar\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1625, in predicate
raise MissingRole(item)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRole: Role 'Admin' is required to run this command.

````
from discord.ext import commands

prefix = '.'
token = '123456789'


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot running')

@client.command()
@commands.has_role("Admin")
async def addrole(ctx):
    user = ctx.message.author
    role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="Test_Role")
    await client.add_roles(user, role)


client.run(token)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u only want people with admin perms to be able to use it then replace this line `@commands.has_role("Admin")` with `@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because the person invoking the command does not have `Admin` role. Try removing `@commands.has_role("Admin")` decorator if you want this command to be available to everyone. If not then this error is completly normal and you can handle it with `on_error` event.

Answer (score -1):

client.run(token)```
change to client.run(token)
I think

Comment: client.run(token)```

Comment: remove this ```

Comment: No. These characters are just code-fencing that was badly formatted in the question. This was not part of the original code.